# Setting footnote ragged right in standard class

Tags: horizontal-alignment, footnotes

I am trying to set the footnote ragged right instead of justified. However I am not able to get it working. Below is a MWE

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{expl3}
\usepackage{xparse}
\raggedright

\ExplSyntaxOn
\makeatletter
\RenewDocumentCommand\@makefntext{+m}{
  \group_begin:
  \raggedright
  \leavevmode\normalfont
  \hbox_to_wd:nn{0pt}{\hss\@thefnmark\enspace}
  #1
  \group_end:
}
\makeatother
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

A\footnote{Non eram nescius, Brute, cum, quae summis ingeniis exquisitaque
  doctrina philosophi Graeco sermone tractavissent, ea Latinis litteris
  mandaremus, fore ut hic noster labor in varias reprehensiones incurreret. nam
  quibusdam, et iis quidem non admodum indoctis, totum hoc displicet
  philosophari. quidam autem non tam id reprehendunt, si remissius agatur, sed
  tantum studium tamque multam operam ponendam in eo non arbitrantur. erunt
  etiam, et ii quidem eruditi Graecis litteris, contemnentes Latinas, qui se
  dicant in Graecis legendis operam malle consumere. postremo aliquos futuros
  suspicor, qui me ad alias litteras vocent, genus hoc scribendi, etsi sit
  elegans, personae tamen et dignitatis esse negent.}

\end{document}
```

[image]
I am attempting two things, first is to set the number before each footnote in normal face, protruded to the left, instead of a raised small number. This part works fine. The other part is to set the text ragged right instead of justified. However, neither the use of `\raggedright` inside `\@makefntext` or document-wise, seems to have any effect on the footnote.

Is there any way achieve ragged footnote setting without redefining the whole `\footnote` macro, or `\@footnotetext`, but only the inner most `\@makefntext`?

**Edit**
I found that I missed `\par` after `#1`, which makes all the different. I will leave the question open, either one has a better solution, or someone else find it useful, as I didn't find anything answer this question (there's one for `memoir` though).

Comment: By the way, `\normalfont` doesn't affect the size at all.

Comment: @cfr I merely use it to ensure that it use the document main font, if for any possible reason that it was changed at that point. The font size was left to be `\footnotesize` as intended

Comment: But you said you wanted to change as little as possible. So fine if you want to change more, but then you are embarked on a different project.

Comment: @cfr I meant I do not want to replicate other work of `\footnote`, for example, the skips around footnotes, etc., which I would need t do if I redefine an "outer" macro such as `\footnote` instead of the inner most one `\@makefntext`. Anyway, I wasn't phrasing it clear. sorry for the confusion.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need the `\raggedright` to be active when the paragraph ends. I am not sure why you've added a group, since there is none in the original definition. Nor am I sure why you've added `\normalfont` which will do nothing to change the size.

Why not just this?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{kantlipsum}
\usepackage{xparse}
% \raggedright

\ExplSyntaxOn
\makeatletter
\RenewDocumentCommand\@makefntext{+m}{
  \raggedright
  \leavevmode
  \hbox_to_wd:nn{0pt}{\hss\@thefnmark\enspace}
  #1
}
\makeatother
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\kant[1]

A\footnote{Non eram nescius, Brute, cum, quae summis ingeniis exquisitaque
  doctrina philosophi Graeco sermone tractavissent, ea Latinis litteris
  mandaremus, fore ut hic noster labor in varias reprehensiones incurreret. nam
  quibusdam, et iis quidem non admodum indoctis, totum hoc displicet
  philosophari. quidam autem non tam id reprehendunt, si remissius agatur, sed
  tantum studium tamque multam operam ponendam in eo non arbitrantur. erunt
  etiam, et ii quidem eruditi Graecis litteris, contemnentes Latinas, qui se
  dicant in Graecis legendis operam malle consumere. postremo aliquos futuros
  suspicor, qui me ad alias litteras vocent, genus hoc scribendi, etsi sit
  elegans, personae tamen et dignitatis esse negent.}

\kant[2]
\end{document}
```

[image: ragged right footnote]

I commented the `\raggedright` in the preamble just to show you can do this even if you want only footnotes ragged right and the body text justified. Obviously, uncomment it if you want it all ragged right.

`xparse` etc. seems overkill here. Why not just

```
\makeatletter
\renewcommand\@makefntext[1]{%
  \raggedright
  \leavevmode
  \rlap{\hss\@thefnmark\enspace}%
  #1%
}
\makeatother
```

which does the same? Although, admittedly the `%`ing gets annoying.

Comment: I figured out this reason out myself, though my solution was simply to add an `\par` at the end before exiting the `group` (see my edit). I still feel more conformable to have them inside a group that I know of. But I will accept this answer anyway. Thanks

Comment: @YanZhou I worry that adding a `\par` will produce unintended and undesirable side-effects at some point.

Comment: That's a good point

Comment: adding `\par` within a footnote isn't recommended, but it's okay to add `\endgraf` there.  (it's a plain tex equivalent to the primitive `\par`, without all the extra stuff that latex loads onto `\par`.)

Comment: @YanZhou Please see barbara's comment above.

Comment: @barbarabeeton Wasn't `\par` a primitive and `\endgraf` another name `\let` to it? I used `texdef` to to try to find out what "undesirable" effect `\par` could have, and there seems to be nothing and its not redefined.

Comment: @YanZhou -- yes, `\par` is a ("original tex") primitive, but lates redefines it all over the place.  look into `latex.ltx` for `\par` and `\@setpar` and you'll see the consequences.  `\endgraf` retains the original primitive meaning, so can be used safely in places where the redefined `\par` would explode.

Comment: @barbarabeeton Thanks for the clarification